# Insert more than one row in database at the same time c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading

I try to write on database in multi-Thread at the same time
but the error occurred in myCommand.Connection.Open(); 
The error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
How can I Solve this problem ?

This example show the problem

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into table(a,b)values(1,'aaa')", Connection);
            myCommand.Connection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myCommand.Connection.Close();
        }).Start();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into table(a,b)values(2,'aaa')", Connection);
            myCommand.Connection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myCommand.Connection.Close();
        }).Start();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into table(a,b)values(3,'aaa')", Connection);
            myCommand.Connection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myCommand.Connection.Close();
        }).Start();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into table(a,b)values(4,'aaa')", Connection);
            myCommand.Connection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myCommand.Connection.Close();
        }).Start();
    }
```

Comment: Where's the `Connection` coming from?

Comment: This will bottlenecked by the server...

Comment: @Killercam What is the best way to insert more than one row in database at the same time c#

Comment: You can request seperate thread for asynchronous execution of the Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure of choice by using [`SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CMD.BEGINEXECUTENONQUERY);k(BEGINEXECUTENONQUERY);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true)...

Comment: after couple days I understand your comment SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a valid connection:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(...);
connection.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(...);
command.Connection = connection;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unclear why you need/want to do that, In SQL2K8 you could simply use a table valued constructor in a single batch for < 1k rows;

`insert into table(a,b)values(1,'aaa'),(2,'aaa'),(3,aaa)`

Comment: It's not that simple I have multi-threading in my project and ÷ want to insert in each thread differently from the rest